# Understanding typescript structual typesystem

Tags: typescript, types

Why is this example ok in Typescript:

```
class Person {
    name: String;
    age: number;
}

class Customer {
    name: String;
}

const cust: Customer = new Person();
```

But not this example?

```
type Boj = {boj: number};
let b: Boj = {boj: 3, jj: 3};
```

Should not both work with a structual typesystem?

Comment: You're telling TS that `b` is of type `Boj`. `Boj` does not have a `jj` property, so you can't assign it... That's the entire point of TypeScript: Type safety. If you want to assign properties regardless of type, use `any` or just don't use TypeScript.

Comment: @Cerbrus, actually this is special case where Typescript checks extra properties. Only object literals have excess property checking, otherwise extra properties are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior in second example is called *[excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)*

> TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in this code. Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error

This applies **only** to object literals. Assigning variable with extra properties is still allowed:

```
type Boj = { boj: number };

const foo = { boj: 3, jj: 3 }; // inferred type is { boj: number; jj: number; }
let b: Boj = foo; // no error here, foo is not object literal
```

Comment: Note that the handbook currently doesn't have non-deprecated documentation for excess property checking (not sure why).  Recently I've been pointing to [the documentation for the feature's release in TS1.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) instead, even though it doesn't have as much useful info in there.